# why spark job don't work on zepplin while they work when using pyspark shell

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

i'am trying to execute the following code on zepplin

```
df = spark.read.csv('/path/to/csv')
df.show(3)
```

but i get the following error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o786.collectToPython. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 39.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 39.0 (TID 326, 172.16.23.92, executor 0): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateParser; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2, local class serialVersionUID = 3
```

i have hadoop-2.7.3 running on 2 nodes cluster and spark 2.3.2 running on standalone mode and zeppelin 0.8.1, this problem only occur when using zepplin
and i have the SPARK_HOME in zeppelin configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem was that zeppelin was using a commons-lang3-3.5.jar and spark using commons-lang-2.6.jar so all i did is to add the jar path to zeppelin configuration on the interpreter menu:

1-Click 'Interpreter' menu in navigation bar.

2-Click 'edit' button of the interpreter which you want to load dependencies to.

3-Fill artifact and exclude field to your needs. Add the path to the respective jar file.

4-Press 'Save' to restart the interpreter with loaded libraries.

Comment: What exactly did you put in the artifact section of the Spark interpreter? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin is using its commons-lang2 jar to stream to Spark executors while Spark local is using common-lang3. like Achref mentioned, just fill out artifact location of commons-lang3 and restart interpreter then you should be good.